# Google analytics filter RegEXp assistance

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a filter that only shows me data with /documents/ in the URL. I need to modify the filter so i can get /documents/ and /getattachment/.

For the Filter Pattern could i use: "/documents/|/getattachment/", assuming the pipe is an OR?

Comment: Yes you can use `/documents/|/getattachment/`, you may also use `/(documents|getattachment)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have repeating patterns, you may consider shortening the final pattern.

I'd recommend using a [*grouping construct*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with [*alternation*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/(documents|getattachment)/
```

Now, the pattern will mean:

- `/`  - a slash
- `(documents|getattachment)` - either one word or the other
- `/` - a slash

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. And for the explanation too, it helps!

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer.